# What are Jack Jack's powers?

Tags: the-incredibles

Jack Jack is shown in the Incredibles to have super powers. We first get hints to this with Kari making frantic calls to Helen about him acting "Reeeaaaalllllyyy weird." Later when <s>Buddy</s> <s>Incredi-boy</s> Syndrome tries to kidnap Jack Jack he starts turning into a variety of different things.

The short "Jack-Jack Attack" also shows use of his Powers but I haven't seen it to say what.

With the release of the Incredibles II teaser trailer we've been shown signs of Jack Jack with even more powers.

Do we know what powers Jack Jack has? Or at least what ones he's showed signs of to date?

Comment: Some of his powers are also shown in [Jack-Jack Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack-Jack_Attack)

Comment: He's the Jack of all trades basically! ;)

Comment: @Nolimon Ah nice one hadn't heard of that before, edited it into the question as a reference point.

Comment: http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Jack-Jack_Parr#Powers_and_Abilities

Comment: Just a thought, but it's possible that his powers will eventually focus one and forget all the others as he ages up?

Comment: From sister site [Jack-Jack's powers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/89921/1190)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The powers we know so far are

- Self-immolation (*The Incredibles*, *Incredibles 2*, [Jack-Jack Attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xF47FXtelQ))

  [image]
- Eye lasers (*Incredibles 2* trailer, *Incredibles 2*)

  [image]
- Phasing through objects and/or dimensional shifting (*Incredibles 2*, Jack-Jack Attack)

  [image]
- Transforming into some sort of demon (*The Incredibles*, *Incredibles 2*)

  [image]
- Some as-yet unexplored lightning power (*Incredibles 2 Trailer*, *Incredibles 2*)

  [image]
- Molecular change of some sort. He becomes so heavy Syndrome drops him (*The Incredibles*)

  [image]
- Teleportation (Jack-Jack Attack)
- Levitation (Jack-Jack Attack)

  [image]
- Super strength (Jack-Jack Attack) 
  The crate in question was securing him and he was shown chewing it before this

  [image]
- Self-cloning (*Incredibles 2*)

  [image]
- Shapeshifting (*Incredibles 2*) - Jack Jack takes on Edna's facial features at one point

  [image]
- Growth (*Incredibles 2*) - Jack Jack grows in size inside the ship

  [image]

Comment: The huge number of powers here makes me think that they are going to do some sort of "You lose abilities as you mature, but the ones you keep you gain more control and power over"

Comment: @NathanMerrill Thats pretty much exactly what they said in Incredibles 2 actually!